# Interactive dataframe sorting using Google Colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, ipywidgets, qgrid

I've recently been trying to create an interactive plotting platform using a pandas dataframe in Google Colab. The idea is to either create my own or use an existing platform such as `qgrid` or Colab's `Data Table`. The problem with `qgrid` is that it does not render in Google Colab due to a package dependency error with `ipywidgets`. The problem with Colab's `Data Table` is that I cannot figure out how to restore the sorted table as a `pandas DataFrame`.

Alternatively I could create my own querying system, but I would much prefer to use one of these or a different platform. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Interactive Data Table

```
pip install pandas-datareader

from pandas_datareader import wb

pip install itables

from itables import init_notebook_mode
init_notebook_mode(all_interactive=True)

df = wb.get_countries()
df

sorted = df.sort_values(by=['name'], ascending=True)
sorted
```